# Issue in GAPP not install in Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, emulation, genymotion

i want to install **GAPP** zip in genymotion emulator so i follow all steps which is given in docs in below link

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

but when i install **GAPPS** zip for any version like **4.2, 4.4 , 5.0** it gave me error like below image

any idea how can i solve this problem ? your all suggestion s is appreciable

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That's not an error. You have to press OK to install it :).